# API parameter google App Engine(java)

Tags: java, api, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am developing google endpoints API's but I got unexpected output from following code.
when I insert email **myemail@hostname.com** then endpoint API convert this email to **myemail%40hostname.com** so could you please tell me how can I solve this issue?

```
@ApiMethod(name="login")
    public User userLogin(@Named("email")final String email,@Named("password")final String pwd)
    {   
        return userLoginResponse(email, pwd);   
    }
```

Comment: Is it being sent as myemail%40hostname.com to the function?

Comment: yes It sent myemail%40hostname.com to the function

Answer (score 0):

Special characters like "@" are encoded using UTF-8. 
Use the `URLDecoder` class to decode the email id.

```
import java.net.URLDecoder;

...

@ApiMethod(name="login")
    public User userLogin(@Named("email")final String email,@Named("password")final String pwd)
    {   

        try {
            decodedEmail = URLDecoder.decode(email,"UTF-8");
        } 

        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return userLoginResponse(decodedEmail, pwd);   
    }
```

Comment: is there another way to pass parameter to API method?(because if I have  multiple parameters for API method which contains special characters then I have to decode each one)

Comment: I don't think you need to decode the parameters in production code, this appears to happen only in the local development server